# Pandas fill value in another column depending upon GroupBy values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

How can we create a new column, i.e. `error_flag_type`, whose value depends upon the groupby at `student_id`

The data looks like this:

| student_id | subject_id | error | team |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | yes | A |
| 1 | 2 |  | A |
| 1 | 3 |  | A |
| 1 |  | yes | A |
| 2 | 4 |  | B |
| 2 | 5 |  | B |
| 2 |  | yes | B |
| 3 | 6 |  | B |
| 3 | 7 |  | B |
| 3 | 8 |  | B |
| 3 | 9 | yes | B |
| 4 | 10 |  | A |
| 4 | 11 |  | A |
| 4 | 12 |  | A |

And step by step operation looks like this: 
 
1/4) If both `student_id` and `subject_id` has value ***yes*** in the `error` column

| student_id | subject_id | error | team |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | yes | A |
| 1 | 2 |  | A |
| 1 | 3 |  | A |
| 1 |  | yes | A |

Thus, outcome:

| student_id | error | team | error_flag_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | yes | A | both |

2/4) If only `subject_id` has value **yes**_ in the `error` column

| student_id | subject_id | error | team |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 4 |  | B |
| 2 | 5 |  | B |
| 2 |  | yes | B |

Becomes:

| student_id | error | team | error_flag_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | yes | B | student_id_level |

3/4)

| student_id | subject_id | error | team |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 6 |  | B |
| 3 | 7 |  | B |
| 3 | 8 |  | B |
| 3 | 9 | yes | B |

Becomes

| student_id | error | team | error_flag_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | yes | B | subject_id_level |

4/4)

| student_id | subject_id | error | team |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 10 |  | A |
| 4 | 11 |  | A |
| 4 | 12 |  | A |

Becomes

| student_id | error | team | error_flag_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | no_error | A | no_error |

Looking at all the individual steps together as:

| student_id | error | team | error_flag_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | yes | A | both |
| 2 | yes | B | student_id_level |
| 3 | yes | B | subject_id_level |
| 4 | no_error | A | no_error |

Comment: is it both for student_id 1 because student_id == subject_id in the first row? then if the yes was rather in the second row, the output would be student_id_level?

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this using ordered `Categorical`, this will give you flexibility to chose the order of the errors/flags. Then a simple `groupby.agg` with max gives you the highest warning:

```
m1 = df['student_id'].eq(df['subject_id'])
m2 = df['error'].eq('yes')

(df.assign(error=pd.Categorical(df['error'].fillna('no_error'),
                                categories=['no_error', 'yes'],
                                ordered=True),
           error_flag_type=pd.Categorical(np.select([m1&m2, m2],
                                                    ['both', 'student_id_level'],
                                                    'no_error'
                                                   ),
                                          categories=['no_error',
                                                      'student_id_level',
                                                      'both'],
                                          ordered=True
                                         )
          )
    .groupby('student_id', as_index=False)
    .agg({'error': 'max', 'team': 'first', 'error_flag_type': 'max'})
)
```

output:

```
   student_id     error team   error_flag_type
0           1       yes    A              both
1           2       yes    B  student_id_level
2           3       yes    B  student_id_level
3           4  no_error    A          no_error
```